# Where is Pitru Loka among the 14 lokas?

Tags: scripture, lokas, pitru

> My dear son Nārada, know from me that there are seven lower planetary
>   systems out of the total fourteen. The first planetary system, known
>   as Atala, is situated on the waist; the second, Vitala, is situated on
>   the thighs; the third, Sutala, on the knees; the fourth, Talātala, on
>   the shanks; the fifth, Mahātala, on the ankles; the sixth, Rasātala,
>   on the upper portion of the feet; and the seventh, Pātāla, on the
>   soles of the feet. Thus the virāṭ form of the Lord is full of all
>   planetary systems. (Srimad Bhagavatam 2:5:40-41)

The universe is divided into fourteen planetary systems. Seven planetary systems, called Bhūr, Bhuvar, Svar, Mahar, Janas, Tapas and Satya, are upward planetary systems, one above the other. There are also seven planetary systems downward, known as Atala, Vitala, Sutala, Talātala, Mahātala, Rasātala and Pātāla, gradually, one below the other.

Pitr are souls of those who are deceased from the family. Where is Pitra loka situated?

How are Pitr related to Pitr loka? When do they come here? For how much time do they stay in Pitr loka?

Comment: Answer the following questions and I'll put in my answer. Conflicts and differences apart :-), 1) where would one "hope" to find pitr? 2) Let's analyze a bit. If a deceased soul, dislocates from the body what gives it motion? 3) How would it know where to go? What happens to that once it reaches that destination? Assume the time dilation. One day of Pitr = 1 year on Earth, and an equivalent distance dilation.

Answer (score 1):

The verse in the question briefs about the Bila-auspicious planetary system (7 Bila-swarga from waist to feet of the Lord). Below which is Pitra Loka. Lord Vishnuji is sitting on the Shyam rang (Dark Matter) ocean-- is nothing but Garbhodaka Ocean on which cosmic Vishnu rests over SheshNag. Shesha is said to uphold all these parallel **auspicious, Bila-auspicious Universes, naraka universes** on his hoods and constantly sings the glories of the God Vishnu from all his mouths. He is sometimes referred to as Ananta Shesha which translates as endless-Shesha or Adishasha "first Shesha". Now, below Pitra Loka and just slightly above this Garbhodak ocean resides the suffering universes --7 narakas which Lord Vishnuji usually doesn't casts his special mercy, grace until the time jivas therein sufferring due to evil past deeds, till stipulated suffering duration ends up.

> Vishnu purana described as below:
> Planets from Satya loka to earth(Swarga-Loka) and lower swarga : planets that do not need the Sun for survival (Bila-Swarga). **Below the lowest Bila-swarga planet of Pataal, is the planet of the Manes or ancestors who are known as the >Pitras**.

Beneath all these, and slightly above the Garbhodak ocean, are the Naraklokas, or the hellish planets.

***So, Pitra loka is spatially between the 14 swarga(7-swarga,7-bila swarga) and naraka(hellish abode)***

Note: The visible world we understand is 3-Dimensional, while one needs YOGIC vision to experience 4th dimensional reality and beyond to have better perceptions about these worlds.

***Very important day each year to worship pitra: Mahalaya amavasya(also known as Sarvapitri Amavasya) falling on September 17,2020 this year, following rites properly which helps pitra's step further towards moksha siddhi and descendents free from karmic Pitra dosha due to bad, immature illicit deeds in lifetime which are against the ancestral principles.***

Comment: wrong, Sixth loka or bhuvar loka is called Pitra loka. http://blog.onlineprasad.com/what-are-the-14-lokas-or-worlds-according-to-hindu-mythology/ https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp065.htm  Bhur(Bhumi)-Bhuvan-Swaha(Swarga) are occupied by humans, pitras and gods respectively. pls correct.

Comment: Different places in shastras have mentioned slightly differently. I provided reference from the elaborated description given in the Vishnu purana. **Moreover, in your first link -There's no mention of word specifically ancestors/deceased**. ***While another link simply points Vishnu purana in some of the lines but didn't mention the Pitra loka at all***, please validate the same

Comment: Just study basic gayatri mantra, its start with Om Bhur-Bhuva-Swaha which covers earth, space and heavens for human-pitra-gods. Do you know what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Śrāddha Pitra Paksha for ancestors are? They extend for 14 days because day of Pitra loka is of 14-15days, just like 6months of earth equal to one day of Gods https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttarayana. So,logically Pitra loka is between earth and heaven Swarga of 5th realm .Where its written Pitra loka is below 14th loka Patala of Nagas?

Comment: Gayatri mantra is the mantra to appease Savitṛ- sun God, not pitras.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111807/discussion-between-saurabh-t-jain-and-manu-kumar).

Comment: @ManuKumar and Saurabh, please adhere to [code of conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct). Personal attacks aren't acceptable. If you're having clashes in thoughts, please take a break.

Comment: Noted, thanks, will mark you if anyone starts the same without any reason.

Comment: @Saurabh Please use flag option in case anyone abuse or being rude to you.